# How to make auto-layout constraint dependent on multiple other anchors?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

How can auto-layout be used to make a view's height equal to the sum of two other view's heights?

For example:

```
viewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ...),
viewB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ...),
viewC.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewA.heightAnchor + viewB.heightAnchor)
```

Is there a solution that does not involve setting a constant value and recalculating it on every view bounds change?

Comment: There is no method in the apis can accomplish what you want the only solution is to deal with equalToConstant

Comment: Create a LayoutGuide that is constrained to the top of ViewA and bottom of ViewB and then constrain your height anchor of ViewC to that layout guide (Have not tested it yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can*, but only with the help of some helper views, I think. See this example playground I just now cooked up that achieves this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let vc = UIViewController()
vc.view = UIView()
vc.view.backgroundColor = .white

let viewA = UIView()
let viewB = UIView()
let viewC = UIView()

viewA.backgroundColor = .red
viewB.backgroundColor = .green
viewC.backgroundColor = .blue

viewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
viewB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
viewC.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

vc.view.addSubview(viewA)
vc.view.addSubview(viewB)
vc.view.addSubview(viewC)

let helperViewA = UIView()
let helperViewB = UIView()

helperViewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
helperViewB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

helperViewA.isHidden = true
helperViewB.isHidden = true

vc.view.addSubview(helperViewA)
vc.view.addSubview(helperViewB)

viewA.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
viewA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
viewA.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
viewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true

viewB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
viewB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewA.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
viewB.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
viewB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0).isActive = true

viewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: helperViewA.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
viewB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: helperViewB.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true

helperViewA.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: helperViewB.topAnchor).isActive = true

viewC.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
viewC.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: helperViewA.topAnchor).isActive = true
viewC.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: helperViewB.bottomAnchor).isActive = true


helperViewA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewC.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
helperViewA.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewC.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
helperViewB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewC.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
helperViewB.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewC.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

viewC.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
viewC.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

vc.view.frame.size = CGSize(width: 375, height: 667)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc.view
```

The idea is that you have two helper views stacked vertically on each other, connected by the top one's `bottomAnchor` and the bottom one's `topAnchor`. You then set each of these helper views' heights to be equal to your `viewA` and `viewB` heights. Then, your `viewC` can be attached to the top view's `topAnchor` and the bottom view's `bottomAnchor`, which gives the result of `viewC` being the height of `viewA`'s height plus `viewB`'s height.

Comment: solving it with parent view is not a solution , he needs any 2 separate  views

Comment: @Sh_Khan I don't know what you mean by "solving it with parent view".

Comment: i mean you solve it assuming that both views are directly below each other which may not always be the case and if there is any empty space between them it will be accounted as a plus space > the sum of viewA and ViewB heights

Comment: The _helper_ views are directly above and below each other, yes, but not the views in the OP's question (viewA and viewB).

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler Good workaround, and the only workaround I could think of. Until Apple adds this to their API one could in fact write an extension for NSLayoutAnchor and use your workaround.